# Why/how does "uptime" show CPU load >1?

Tags: uptime, load-average

I have a **1 core CPU** installed on my PC. Sometimes, `uptime` shows load >1. How is this possible and what does this mean?

EDIT: The values go up to `2.4`

Comment: Note: `load` is different from `load average`. As @michas said, load is an indicator for count of processes which are waiting to be executed, but [load average](https://www.tecmint.com/understand-linux-load-averages-and-monitor-performance/) is the average system load calculated over a given period of time of 1, 5 and 15 minutes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Load is not equal to CPU usage. It is basically an indicator how many processes are *waiting* to be executed.

Some helpful links:

- https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-in-unix-linux
- http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes sense. Is there a way to get CPU usage, not load?

Comment: Well generally you could have many CPUs. One could be totally busy and the other just idling. Have a look at `htop` for a nice "graphical" overview.

Comment: this is incorrect. The load average is a metric for how many processes are *ready* to be executed. This includes processes that are waiting, but *also* processes that are *currently executing*. So if the load average is 1, it means that on average (for the given time period) one CPU was in use; if it is two, that means that on average, two CPUs were in use. As such, a particular load average for a single-CPU system is not the same thing as the same load average for a multi-core system.

Comment: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. System load includes processes waiting on the CPU, but *it also includes processes using the CPU and processes waiting on I/O.*  This is exceptionally important because load >1 isn't a problem (nowadays) -- load greater than the number of your cores (not including threads) is a problem with sufficiently large I/O usage.

Answer (score 14):

`uptime` shows *system load* (not exactly CPU usage), which is described in `man uptime` as follows:

> System load averages is the average number of processes that are
> either in a runnable or uninterruptable state.
>
> - A process in a runnable state is either using the CPU or waiting to use the CPU.
> - A process in
>   uninterruptable state is waiting for some I/O access, eg waiting for
>   disk.
>
> The averages are taken over the three time intervals. Load
> averages are not normalized for the number of CPUs in a system, so a
> load average of 1 means a single CPU system is loaded all the time
> while on a 4 CPU system it means it was idle 75% of the time.

As long as the load is less than the number of CPU cores you have, it should be fine. If it gets above, it means that your system is not able to cope with its workload "real time". Thus, some processes need to *wait* to get CPU time (or IO access). A waiting line is created.

If you have a 2.7 load it means that on average (during the last 1, 5 or 15 minutes, depending on the value you look at), 2.7 processes are trying to execute in parallel, but you only have 1 core, so your system is overloaded.
You're asking too much from it.

Don't panic though, it may not be such a problem: once the work is finished, things usually get back to normal.

Answer (score 7):

Uptime shows the output of `/proc/loadavg` for loads.

The manpage of `man 5 proc` says

```
   /proc/loadavg
          The first three fields in this file are load average figures giving
          the  number  of jobs in the run queue (state R) or waiting for disk
          I/O (state D) averaged over 1, 5, and 15  minutes.
```

So you can have high loads even if you have 0% CPU usage. One Core can gain loads up to 100% or 1 on multi processor systems.

See also [High CPU load during I/O](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215819/high-cpu-load-during-i-o)

Answer (score -2):

```
 ps aux --sort -rss |head -15
```

This will sort 15 processes most used by rss memory

Also this will sort most used processes by cpu and memory

```
 ps aux --sort -pid |head -15
```

If you have 1 CPU load more than 1 is warning, examine the process list and see who of them uses the most CPU and RAM

When you see most used processes try to see what files are open with

```
lsof -p [PID_most_used]
```

Also it would be nice if you give ouptut from top command

Comment: rss is not related to load average, what are you on about?