# My server load under 40 is healthy?

Tags: linux, debian, load-average

When I run the following command

```
less  /proc/cpuinfo
```

I get list of 40 CPUs, does that mean my system can load go up to 40 and things still be running smoothly?

Comment: Your system load (as displayed in `top` or `uptime`) is the queue length, not a measure of how much of the available CPU is in use.  If your system load is 40, you are backed up regardless how many CPUs you have.  See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/why-how-does-uptime-show-cpu-load-1)  helpfully loaded in the "Related" sidebar atm.

Comment: so the number of cores is not relevant to system load?

Comment: Uh, it depends. I've seen dual processor solaris systems chugging along without issue at a load of 5000 while a dual processor linux box at that same load was busy corrupting payment batch files.